# Jquery on ready function not doing anything

Tags: jquery, html

Following a tutorial that uses jquery document ready function however I can't get this bit to work or do anything. I threw in an alert and it won't trigger any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Coulthard</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="blanket.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("works");
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slideshownav").css("visibility", "visible");
$("#slideshownav a[href=#image1]".addclass("active");



$("#slideshownav").localScroll({
target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x' });

$("#slideshownav a").click(function(){
    $("#slideshownav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Comment out everything except the alert, to check that the event is in fact being fired. Then add code a small block at a time until it fails, and you'll know where the problem is. In general, if there is a syntax error, the entire block of code will not be executed.

Comment: -1 for not having debugged

Answer (score 1):

There is a closing braket missing, after `a[href=#image1]`.

Change

```
`$("#slideshownav a[href=#image1]".addclass("active");`
```

to

```
`$("#slideshownav a[href=#image1]").addclass("active");`
```

and you should see your alert.

PS: You are using a very outdated version of jQuery. Please look forward to use the current version 1.9.1 on new projects.